# Is the defaultdict in Python's collections module really faster than using setdefault?

Tags: python, collections, defaultdict, setdefault, python-collections

I've seen other Python programmers use defaultdict from the collections module for the following use case:

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]

def main():
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in s:
        d[k].append(v)
```

I've typically approached this problem by using setdefault instead:

```
def main():
    d = {}
    for k, v in s:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

The docs do in fact [claim that using defaultdict is faster](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but I've seen the opposite to be true when testing myself:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s "from withsetdefault import main; s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)];" "main()"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.51 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s "from withdefaultdict import main; s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)];" "main()"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.38 usec per loop
```

Is there something wrong with how I've set up the tests?

For reference, I'm using Python 2.7.3 [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666)

Comment: did one test file contain `s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]` where the other didn't?

Comment: @Claudiu: read the timeit lines carefully.

Comment: You need to use *much* larger test sets where there is more than 2 values per key.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: i did. i don't know what is in `withsetdefault.py` and `withdefaultdict.py`. if one of them contains that line and the other doesn't, that could account for the difference

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there is something "wrong":

You have put the creation of the `(default)dict` into the statement instead of the setup. Constructing a new `defaultdict` is more expensive than a normal `dict`, and usually that's not the bottleneck you should be profiling in a program - after all, you build your data structures once but you use them many times.

If you do your tests like below, you see that `defaultdict` operations are indeed faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup1 = """from collections import defaultdict
... s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
... d = defaultdict(list)"""
>>> stmt1 = """for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)"""
>>> setup2 = """s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
... d = {}"""
>>> stmt2 = """for k, v in s:
...     d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup1, stmt=stmt1)
1.0283400125194078
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup2, stmt=stmt2)
1.7767367580925395
```

Python 2.7.3 on Win7 x64.

Comment: Thanks Tim! When I remove the defaultdict constructor from the test statement, it's definitely faster that using setdefault...regardless of the data size.

Comment: You only talk about constructing the (default)dict being the difference, but I'd say you also have a second difference that might be significant: In the original, 60% of all keys were new and required an insertion and used the `[]`. In your version, due to repeating each snippet a million times, it's almost 0%.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tim's answer, when you make multiple defaultdicts, adding elements becomes costlier. Though initialization adds time, the main difference comes from the time taken to add elements to the multiple defaultdicts.

Here's some code to show the observation

```py
import time
from collections import defaultdict

def time_taken_mult_dd(sz):
    t1 = t2 = 0
    for i1 in range(1000000):
        start1 = time.time()
        d = defaultdict(int)
        end1 = time.time()
        
        start2 = time.time()
        for i2 in range(sz):
            d[i2] += 1
        end2 = time.time()
        
        t1 += end1 - start1
        t2 += end2 - start2
    
    print(f"Time taken for initialization {t1:5.2f}e-06")
    print(f"Time taken for addition       {t2:5.2f}e-06")

def time_taken_one_dd(sz):
    t = 0
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i1 in range(1000000):
        
        start = time.time()
        for i2 in range(sz):
            d[i2] += 1
        end = time.time()
        
        t += end - start
    
    print(f"Time taken for addition       {t:5.2f}e-06")
```

And here's the output. Observe how initialization time remains same while adding elements become more time consuming

```
>>> time_taken_one_dd(10)
Time taken for addition        1.59e-06
>>> time_taken_mult_dd(10)
Time taken for initialization  0.41e-06
Time taken for addition        2.64e-06
>>> 
>>> time_taken_one_dd(50)
Time taken for addition        6.46e-06
>>> time_taken_mult_dd(50)
Time taken for initialization  0.59e-06
Time taken for addition       11.80e-06
>>> 
>>> time_taken_one_dd(100)
Time taken for addition       12.61e-06
>>> time_taken_mult_dd(100)
Time taken for initialization  0.71e-06
Time taken for addition       23.05e-06
```