# Creating a dictionary with multiple values for every key from SQLITE in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

Right now, I am trying to figure out a way to use an SQLITE database to create the following dictionary automatically.

```
produce = {1:[2,4], 2:[1,2,3], 3:[2,3,4]}
```

The key is a factory, the values attached to it are the products, this factory is able to produce. I.e. 1:[2,4] --> Factory one is able to produce products 2 and 4.

In my SQLITE database I have a table with four fields: idfactory[INT], idproduct[INT],production[BOOL]. I am then using the following code to get the relevant dataset:

```
cur.execute('SELECT idfactory,idproduct FROM production WHERE production=1')
result = cur.fetchall()
```

My idea would then be, to use a loop to fill my dictionary, with something like this:

```
for idfactory,idproduct in result:
    p[idfactory] = idproduct
```

However, this code produces an error, and would also be problematic, because there are no unique KEYs in my database.

I am not quite sure if my explanation is sufficient, but any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: may be this? `for id,prod in result: p.setdefault(id,[]).append(prod)`

Comment: And check that `result` is not empty before trying to iterate over it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of `dict` may help.
Try this:

```
p = {}

for idfactory, idproduct in result:
    p.setdefault(idfactory, []).append(idproduct)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job! I will look into the setdefault option.

Answer (score 0):

[`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) [is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555967/is-the-defaultdict-in-pythons-collections-module-really-faster-than-using-setde) than using [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), and in my opinion, a much cleaner way of performing the same action. Consider using this if you want to assume an empty list for all lookups to unknown keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

p = defaultdict(list)
for idfactory, idproduct in result:
    p[idfactory].append(idproduct)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I will look into your suggestion as well. What would you say are the practical implications when using defaultdict over .setdefault?